# Concatenar byte con string en Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

Estoy realizando una aplicación donde detecto datos de un sensor desde Arduino y deseo imprimirlos junto con la fecha y hora. El dato que leo del puerto serial de Arduino es tipo byte, mientras que la fecha y la hora son str.

Quiero concatenar estos datos para imprimirlos con esta linea de código:

```
temperatura = ser.readline()

time_hhmmss = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
date_mmddyyyy = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(temperatura + ',' + time_hhmmss + ',' + date_mmddyyyy)
```

Pero me lanza este error: TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

He buscado la manera de como concatenarlos pero no lo logro. Les indico que el dato si lo logro capturar desde Arduino. Espero su ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es tan sencillo como convertir de `bytes` a `str` (por defecto, codificado en `utf-8`):

```
print(temperatura.decode() + ',' + time_hhmmss + ',' + date_mmddyyyy)
```

Aunque se puede mejorar un poco más:

```
from datetime import datetime

temperatura = ser.readline()

print("{} ºC, {:%H:%M:%S, %d/%m/%Y}".format(temperatura.decode(), datetime.now())
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esta forma de concatenar, debería servir tanto en Python 3 como en Python 2:

```
print(",".join((temperatura,time_hhmmss,date_mmddyyyy)))
```

Comment: No funciona en Python 3